# NavigationDrawer on right managed by fragment or not?

Tags: android

I use this library:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

I would like to have a right NavigationDrawer with a ListView (or a lot of items) inside and I get items from DB inside the Fragment and when user click on items on the NavigationDrawer I get data from another DB and show it on Fragment.

and I have a questions:
is possible to create a right Drawer inside a Fragment? or is better to create a new right Drawer in MainActivity and change the navigation item inside the Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Just use brand new `Navigation View` from recenlty released [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) by Google.
Here are links for you:

- official documentation, always a good read: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html
- nicely written blog post about Navigation View: http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/
- and last but not least, sample app using new Android Design Library: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp

To have `Navigation View` on the right, just set `android:layout_gravity` to `end`.

Answer (score 1):

As from design point of view, you should always use left sided Navigation Drawer, it is possible to make it right sided, but its recommended to leave it at the left side.

Another thing is that you do not need to use 3rd party navigation drawer libraries.Since there is a Design library by google, which supports the material design navigation view.

Here is a link for the library:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

And here is another useful link:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Design-Support-Library

Here is the link for the Navigation Drawer: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

As for your question the appropriate way is to create the drawer always in the main activity onCreate() method.